# Css fill parent

Tags: html, css

I want the blue div to not overflow the red div but always fill parent. I check on stackoverflow and they advised using height:100% but since the child have padding, it overflows. How to do that without changing the style of class parent ?

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width:300px;
}
.child{
  height: 100%;
  padding:20px;
  width:100px;
 background: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width:300px;
}
.child{
  height: 100%;
  padding:20px;
  width:100px;
 background: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` or you can calculate height of children like `height: calc(100% - 40px */ Your padding */`

> Solution1

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}

.child{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

> Solution2

```
.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}

.child{
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```